# jquery ajax POST size limit?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, codeigniter, post

I’m using jquery to send text back to my ajax.php controller like this:

```
var dataString = "1234567890";      
$.post(
    '../ajax/save',
    { data: dataString },
    function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    "text");
```

It works well, that is until the dataString gets to be ~3500 characters long.  At that upper limit (~3.5 KB), the $_POST received by ajax.php is NULL.  Why?

(My php.ini post_max_size = 64M, so it’s not that.)

My setup: Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.9, and CodeIgniter 1.7.1.

Comment: Refer Author:regilero 's comment on thread of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  For some reason NetBeans' debugger tells me $_POST['data'] is null, but it's not. To manually determine the size of the `$_POST` received, I used these calls:

```
$request = http_build_query($_POST);
$size = strlen($request);
```

Also, I was putting $_POST['data'] into CodeIgniter's session:

```
$event_array = array('event' => $_POST['data']);
$this->session->set_userdata($event_array);
```

Which was coming up empty leading me to further believe that $_POST was empty. But the problem was instead `$this->session`, which apparently has a 4K size limit (according to [this post](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/75166/)).