# PHP/Apache/AJAX - POST limit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm trying to send POST data that is 2 million characters big (non-binary string) via ajax (jQuery) and it always comes up as blank on the PHP side.  Here is my code:

```
var string = "<data string that is 2M chars long>";
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data.php',
    data: {'data_string': string}
});
```

On the PHP side, I get the following error message (when trying to retrieve data from `$_POST['data_string']`):

```
Notice: Undefined index: data_string in data.php on line ...
```

I've checked the `post_max_size` in php.ini, and it's set at 256M which should be more than enough?  I'm stumped and not sure what I'm doing wrong...

EDIT: If I make `"string"` a small amount of data (e.g. `var string = 'test'`) then `$_POST["data_string"]` returns `test`, as expected.  So I'm wondering if there's some sort of data limit I'm reaching in Apache2, PHP or the browser itself?  I'm using Google Chrome 17.0.963.79

EDIT2: `memory_limit = 256M` in php.ini

EDIT3: `max_input_time = -1` in php.ini

EDIT4: var_dump($_POST) returns Array(0)

EDIT5: running the latest stable version of PHP5 on debian squeeze: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 10 2012 14:12:26)

Comment: Does the same error persist with significantly smaller strings, such as `test`? Undefined index makes it seem as though it isn't being posted.

Comment: no, error does not persist with small text data.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_POST);` if there's nothing, check apache config files for possible limits

Comment: what php version are you using? php underwent some invasive changes to post data handling recently due to a hash collision DOS attack.

Comment: Each HTTP server implementation (Apache, IIS, etc) has its own setting for data limit on POST operations. If you're able to configure the server, you can change the limit in an .htaccess file.

Comment: could be running into browser string size / memory limit.. test string length before sending

Comment: I would also check the request header if your browser actually did include your 2M string. Maybe you went into some of Chrome's or even jQuery's limitations.

Comment: Basti: the request header actually does show the entire 2M string on Chrome.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You'll have to check the limits parameters on all items between you and the server. Quite hard for proxy servers if any, but at least you can check:

Apache:

- [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), around 2Gb by default, maybe greater for 64bits, check error logs for details.

PHP:

- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) which is directly related to the POST size
- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) which may be unrelated, not sure
- [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time), if the POSt takes too long
- [max_input_nesting_level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level) if your data is an array with a lot of sublevels
- [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), but quite sure it's not that
- [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), as you may reach a size exceding the subprocess allowed memory
- [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), if your data array has many elements

If you have reached the compiled in limit for Apache your only solution is to avoid direct POSt of such a big chunk of data, you'll have to break it into pieces.

Comment: thanks, i suspect the string is too big and I'll probably just break it up into pieces.

Comment: Thanks for this, `max_input_vars` was the culprit for us.

Answer (score 3):

You may also check the suhosin.ini settings, eg.:

```
suhosin.post.max_value_length = 65000
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to set [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and your [memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

EDIT: You may also want to `console.log(string)`; or `console.log(string.length);`  before your request to verify it's being set properly, and also check your request in firebug or chromes developer tools to verify your data is being sent.

Comment: memory_limit = 256M, set_time_limit(0) did not change anything.

Comment: there's also a max_input_time ini setting. also check that your changes to in fact take effect

Comment: I set max_input_time to be -1, and the problem is still there.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Adding Respond Box After Selected Field
$( '[maxlength]' ).bind('click keyup', function(){
    var RespondBox = '<div class="StPgRp" id="UpdateRespond"></div>';
    $('#UpdateRespond').remove();
    $(this).after(RespondBox);
});

//Counting Maximum Characters Allowed In Selected Field
$( '[maxlength]' ).bind('click keyup', function(){
    var MaxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    var CurrentLength = $(this).val().length;
    var Remainder = MaxLength - CurrentLength;
    $('#UpdateRespond').html('You have ' + Remainder + ' characters remaining.');
});

//Checking the PHP Function if YES then send message to user
$( '.Check' ).bind('click keyup', function(){
    var Check = $(this).parent().children('.Check').val();
});
```

Add this to your .js file linked to your page and your sorted!