# Why I get 403, when doing an XHR POST with all the html content of a page? IT's on the same domain

Tags: jquery, post, xmlhttprequest, large-data

When doing
$.post('actions.php',{ content: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' }, function(data){});

It works i get 200 OK.

But when doing:

$.post('actions.php',{ content: escape($('body').html()) }, function(data){});

I get 403, error FORBIDDEN.

Any idea why? It's on the same domain, so i'm not violating SOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post size may be an issue for this.

You can go through your server error logs and you can figure out the reason.

for error logs http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing a post limit overload.

Take a look at this post:
[PHP/Apache/AJAX - POST limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit)