# JQuery's $.post sometimes work sometimes return 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Sometimes I get a 403 forbidden error, I can't see what's wrong.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './ajax-conf-editc.php',
        data: { conf_id: Id, conf_contenido: data },
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){
            if ( msg == '1' || msg == 1){
                var confname = $('#nameConf').val();
                $.cookie('SUCCESS', 'Se ha guardado el contenido de la configuración "' + confname + '".', { expires : 1, path : '/' });
                $(window.location).attr('href', 'index.php');
            } else {
                $('#conf-editc-form').removeAlertBoxes();
                $('#conf-editc-form').alertBox(msg, {type: 'error'});
            }
        }
    });
```

With this data work fine:

> conf_id=11&conf_contenido=%2523tabs-0%253CtabContent%253E%253Cp%253EContenido%253C%2Fp%253E%253CtabTitle

But when I send this, fail and return me an 403 Forbidden

> conf_id=11&conf_contenido=%2523tabs-0%253CtabContent%253E%253Cp%253E%253Ca%2520onclick%253D%2522javascript%253A%2524%2528%2520%2527%2523tabs%2527%2520%2529.tabs%2528%257Bselected%253A1%257D%2529%253Bscroll%25280%252C0%2529%2522%2520href%253D%2522javascript%253Avoid%25280%2529%253B%2522%253EContenido%253C%2Fa%253E%253C%2Fp%253E%253CtabTitle%253EInicio%253Ctabs%253E%2523tabs-1%253CtabContent%253E%253Cp%253EContenido%25201%253C%2Fp%253E%253CtabTitle%253Edos

I hope someone can help me and can tell me why is this happen?

this is the message i get when fail:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /kidspc2/configuraciones/ajax-conf-editc.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

EDIT: Could be mod_security doing this? how can't i check it?

EDIT: i resolve this, enconding conf_content value in Base64.

Comment: Are there any entries in the server `error_log` that show the reason for the 403?

Comment: What are you trying to send in conf_contenido?

Comment: Have you tried looking into Chrome or Firebug network panels to see exactly what the request is, what data is posted to it and what the response / markup returned is for those which do work?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9691395/138071 you might have a limit on the length of the data to receive

Comment: This likely has little to do jQuery and everything to do with what the PHP script is doing.

Comment: conf_contenido has the value of a tinymce instance

Comment: There are not entries in error_log

Comment: @andresdescalzo i don't think the size be the problem, because i'm sending more long strings and is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the dot in the url and the slash

Change this `./ajax-conf-editc.php`  to this `ajax-conf-editc.php` and tell me what you get.

Comment: Are yoy sure that is there any difference between './ajax-conf-editc.php' and 'ajax-conf-editc.php'?

Comment: Yes - ./ goes to the application root and so its expecting the page to be in the application root, no ./ is on the same level as the current page.

Comment: In fact now that I think about it ./ might just take you to the next level up.. either way it is a different result.

Comment: no, I have just realize that allready works for the first case. so it's not going to fix your script, but I have never seen the ./ before

Comment: to move to a level up do you should type ../ instead of ./?

Comment: I can't remember - I think `./` is the same as `../`, or it might be the same as just `/`. I'll have to give it a try sometime but right now I'm too busy.

Comment: / this is for absolute and this is for ../ move up in relative urls but ./ this I have never seen before

Comment: `./` is the current directory and changes nothing. `./ != ../`

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy I know this is old, and please don't take this the wrong way, but, you can not possibly be too busy to research the correct answer if you're not too busy to post your comment. BTW, for the record, the number of periods before the slash have very distinct meanings, and some of these comments are incorrect. Zero dots means Root directory, one dot means Current directory, and two dots means Parent directory. Be careful with Root directory, because it doesn't mean the "Real Root" directory of the Machine in a Web Context, but rather it means the Web Server's "Document Root".

Comment: It occurs to me that 1 dot and 2 dots can refer to the same location if you are already at the top-most directory. Attempting to go higher from the top-most will quietly land you at the same place.

Comment: @UncaAlby - I do see your point but, back in those days, I was working ~100 hour weeks (shed loads of overtime) and, compared to now, I was a noob. So at the time I didn't have time to try it out - I likely just stumbled across this whilst doing research for an issue I was experiencing. I could've refrained from commenting if I wasn't sure of my answer, granted, but I posted it as a *comment* rather than an *answer* because of this so at least it was suggested. If I'm certain of something, I will always add it as an answer. In this case I was just suggesting possible meanings.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy no worries, we've all been down that road!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your $.ajax is requested more than once in a very short interval of time that is why you are getting this 404 error. 
you can fix it by canceling all the previous ajax call and make a new ajax call for latest ajax call request. Hope this helps.

Like the below code:

```
    if( this.ajax ){
            this.ajax.abort();
        }
        this.ajax=$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './ajax-conf-editc.php',
        data: { conf_id: Id, conf_contenido: data },
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){
        if ( msg == '1' || msg == 1){
            var confname = $('#nameConf').val();
            $.cookie('SUCCESS', 'Se ha guardado el contenido de la configuración "' + confname +        '".', { expires : 1, path : '/' });
            $(window.location).attr('href', 'index.php');
        } else {
            $('#conf-editc-form').removeAlertBoxes();
            $('#conf-editc-form').alertBox(msg, {type: 'error'});
        }
    }
});
```