# Audio Upload in Ember giving Request Entity Too Large error

Tags: php, ajax, ember.js

I get the following error when trying to upload an audio file via an ajax POST request in an Ember.js app:

> Request Entity Too Large
>
> The requested resource songuploader.php does not
>   allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided
>   inthe request exceeds the capacity limit. Additionally, a 404 Not
>   Founderror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request.

I've been able to upload files under 1MB successfully, but anything larger is giving me that error.

I've tried all the suggestions on other posts here regarding increasing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, as well as the memory_limit, and nothing has worked so far.

An interesting difference between my error and the others I've seen here is that even though I am sending a POST request the error references a GET request. Could this be causing the issue somehow?

Here's an example request:

```
Request URL:http://www......../songuploader.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:413 Request Entity Too Large

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:7558905
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__utma=252313749.14123192.1368725250.1369847501.1370039629.4; __utmc=252313749; __utmz=252313749.1368725250.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:www...........
Origin:http://www.........
Referer:http://www..........
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
mp3[src]:data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzAwAAAAUwdVRJVDIAAAAFAAAA......
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with another setting on the server side. Take a look at the answer in this post:
[PHP/Apache/AJAX - POST limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit)