# Maximum upload size in PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, filesize

I want to know what is the Maximum upload size in PHP and Apache?
Can i upload more than 2GB file through web browser?

Comment: upload_max_filesize in your php.ini. Yes you can

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit/9691395#9691395

Answer (score 27):

upload_max_filesize in your php.ini
You may want to check post_max_size as well

check this answer for more details
[PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Yes, i want to know can i add any size like 10GB?

Comment: If you want to upload a file via a POST form use:

post_max_size = 20M

(max file size in this example is 20 Megabytes)
If you want to just set the maximum uploadable file size use:

upload_max_filesize = 20M

Both are set in the php.ini file (usually located in /etc/php7.1 or similar).

If this is not explicitly set or your hosting service does not give you the privileges to do this, it may also be possible to set this value in your .htaccess file similar to the following:

php_value upload_max_filesize 20M