# Are there limitations to passing parameters through .post() in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making use of `.post()` quite extensively in my `CMS` application. The example of working code below passes 13 (the most in my application) parameters to the `processing.php` file which works fine.

When the need requires the passing of more parameters I have simply made use of the `action` form property which also works fine.

However, I have an application where there is a need to pass 38 variables including large strings, but at the same time perform a check on the `action file` and if the check fails I need to fire off a `js confirmation alert` to continue or cancel.

I am not quite sure how to fire the `js confirmation alert` from the `processing.php` file and how to return to the originating file with the information entered into the form intact should the user cancel.

I do however understand how to accomplish this if I make use of `.post()`.

## My Question is:

Are there any limitations in the number of parameters one should send to a `processing.php` through `.post()` as written below or is there another approach I should take to handle the above described problem? And if so what would you suggest?

## Example of working code

```
// code element
    $( "#updateDefaultCodeButton" ).click(function(){
        var url = $('#updateDefaultCodeURL').val();     
        var code_font_family = $('#code_font_family').val(); 
        var code_font_color = $('#code_font_color').val();
        var code_font_weight = $('#code_font_weight').val();
        var code_font_size = $('#code_font_size').val();
        var code_bg_color = $('#code_bg_color').val();
        var code_pad_t = $('#code_pad_t').val(); 
        var code_pad_r = $('#code_pad_r').val(); 
        var code_pad_b = $('#code_pad_b').val();
        var code_pad_l = $('#code_pad_l').val(); 
        var code_w_pad_t = $('#code_w_pad_t').val(); 
        var code_w_pad_r = $('#code_w_pad_r').val(); 
        var code_w_pad_b = $('#code_w_pad_b').val();
        var code_w_pad_l = $('#code_w_pad_l').val(); 
        var postit = $.post( url, {
            code_font_family:code_font_family, 
            code_font_color:code_font_color,
            code_font_weight:code_font_weight,
            code_font_size:code_font_size, 
            code_bg_color:code_bg_color,
            code_pad_t:code_pad_t, 
            code_pad_r:code_pad_r, 
            code_pad_b:code_pad_b,
            code_pad_l:code_pad_l,
            code_w_pad_t:code_w_pad_t, 
            code_w_pad_r:code_w_pad_r, 
            code_w_pad_b:code_w_pad_b,
            code_w_pad_l:code_w_pad_l
        });     
        postit.done(function( data ) {window.location.replace("../generator.php?returnto=manage/global-styles-manage.php");});      
    });
```

Comment: As a side note, you would have better to serialize the FORM instead of construct manually the datas to post: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Agree with @A.Wolff. Or at least lose all the variable declarations and grab the values directly in post data object i.e `{ code_font_family: $('#code_font_family').val(), ... }`

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you for your input. This answers the question concerning a better way to perform the task... place it in an answer and I'll give you the check

Comment: @petebolduc @A.Wolff's comment is very good advice, but is definitely not an appropriate answer to your question. Whether you use `.serialize` or not, you're still sending the same amount of data to your server.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the additional information I can definitely see the benefits in performance... bummer though... got a lot of re-programming to do.

Comment: @Andy... point taken and understood... the amount of data being sent has never been the issue... it is well within the limitations of the php.ini... I had read somewhere on this site a while back that making use of `.post()` as below had parameter limitations... greatly appreciate you valued input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Ajax itself doesn't have any limits. The request size is limited on the server however trough various configurations which depend on your environment.

**Apache:**

- `LimitRequestBody`, around 2Gb by default, maybe greater for 64bits, check error logs for details.

**PHP:**

- `post_max_size` which is directly related to the POST size
- `upload_max_filesize` which may be unrelated, not sure
- `max_input_time`, if the POSt takes too long
- `max-input-nesting-level` if your data is an array with a lot of sublevels
- `max_execution_time`, but quite sure it's not that
- `memory_limit`, as you may reach a size exceding the subprocess allowed memory
- `max_input_vars`, if your data array has many elements

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691395/2853903

Comment: Thank you for responding and answering the question about limitations to jQuery Ajax it was the core of my question.

Comment: Would welcome if you could accept the answer as well. :P

Answer (score 6):

The php.ini contains `post_max_size` and `max_input_vars`, both of which can affect the amount you can post to a page.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

You can adjust both if you find yourself above the limit (which will generate a warning in the errorlog).

38 variables should be fine though - `max_input_vars` defaults to 1,000, and `post_max_size` defaults to 2MB (I think) so your text strings would have to be *very* big.

Comment: I do thank you for your input... I appreciate the time you took to both review my question and offer an answer. I voted you up because the answer is both related to and pertinent to post limitations.

Comment: Apologies - I wasn't being sarcastic. I was pointing out that my "input" was talking about "inputs" and that made me smile.