# Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, jquery

i'm trying to post base64 encoded image via ajax then this this error:

The requested resource does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a `413 Request Entity Too Large` error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url('post/saveCanvasImage') ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data:myImage},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check here to change your ajax limits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a miss config of:

`client_max_body_size` 
(nginx)

or

`post_max_size` (PHP)

In any case, im just guessing, please give us more info :)