# phpMyAdmin giving file to large error even with settings bypass

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Alright I am trying to upload a .sql file to phpmyadmin.

I get the error:

```
 You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.
```

After reading some online solutions, I decided to edit my php.ini to allow bigger file uploads.

I changed this:

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

to

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 900M
```

Then restarted apache with no luck.

How can I bypass this limit? Did I do something wrong? Surely the file can't be bigger than 900M because google chrome reported it to be 15MB when downloading. How can I import this file?

Comment: There's more than just `upload_max_filesize`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=upload_max_filesize#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems there are two other php.ini settings to adjust, and there is the UploadDir phpMyAdmin feature that gives you the ability of uploading to a temporary directory and import in phpMyAdmin from this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following lines in your `php.ini` file and update the values as you want.

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Now Restart your apache service.