# How to send Large Encoded base64 Image String from Android to Mysql

Tags: android, mysql

***How to send the Large encoded Image base64 string to server from android*.**

HI Friends,

```
 By default String value within 8000 characters is uploading to server.

 But Encoded Image base64 String length is more than 8000 characters.
```

**More** than **8000 characters** is not uploading from android to mysql database.

please Give me a solution..!

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
       // Log.d("Vicky","I'm out.");

        display(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    }
}

public void display(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap selectedImageBitmap = null;
        try {
            selectedImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selectedImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        selectedImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);}}
```

Comment: seem be a problem server side (mysql) and not client side

Comment: I agree with an_droid_dev

Comment: I tried Datatype MediumText,LongText and Longblob but ,It storing minimum 8000 characters but i need to store more than 8000 characters to server.

Comment: what is the http-request type you are sending ? GET or POST? i doubt this is a web-server issue, not DB as mentioned data types supports way larger than 8K characters. what version of Mysql you are using, and what web-server?

Comment: Webserver: apache 2.4.17              MYSQL VERSION : 10.1.9mariadb       Used GET METHOD to send through android and in php we using same GET METHOD to recieving.

Comment: switch to post, it will work, use TEXT or MEDIUM_TEXT on mysql

Comment: I tried for POST method also and I used VARCHAR,MEDIUM_TEXT,LONGTEXT,LONGblob but it storing within the 8000 characters, would you please send me the some other solutions..!

Comment: @LokeshGPLoki are you tried my solution? VARCHAR(65000)

Comment: can you (on server code) log or write to a file, the length of data received? before inserting in DB, ex, write in a file `$_POST['image_data'];` it's just a temporary thing just to see data size received by server. and if you have access to apache config, see this answer and check limits on your server https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691395/3604083 BTW it could be PHP config issue too, the answer shows all possible limits to check

Answer (score 1):

just check your database structure image field have datatype longblob like below

[image: like this]

Comment: I tried by using longblob,longText,mediumtext, but it not storing more than 8000 characters but it only storing within the 8000 characters.  please give me some other solutions..!

Answer (score 1):

Store the image in a file and save the path of image in your database.

Comment: OP wants to send the image to a remote server, not to store it locally on mobile

Comment: Which language are you using at server side or backend?

Comment: PHP( Codeigniter )

Comment: I don't have knowledge of php. What you need to do is, create a folder in your server through coding, convert your response encoded string to jpg file  and write it to that folder you created.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data type to VARCHAR. Max lenght of it it's around 65000. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(65000);
```

Comment: I tried for 65000, but it shows some error so i used 64000 but it also didnt work.