# large size image is not uploading to live server in laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, file-upload

i want to upload multiple images on server but it is giving me errors below

[image]

i have increased the memory limit size and time execution but still it is giving me error on live site but now it started working on localhost.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);
```

when i upload small size picture on live server then it works properly but when i upload an image of 4 MB then it show error "Site can't be reached"

is there any limitation of memory_limit or execution time on live server or something else??

Any help?

Comment: Which web server do you use? Please have a look at its config. You may have to adjust settings - e.g. max size of posted request body. There are also some more tweaks in php config like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit).

Comment: i dont have server access therefore i increased the memory_limit and execution_time through code but still not working on live server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: it is working properly on localhost through this code 

ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);

but why not on live server?

Comment: Then you have to find out differences between localhost and your live server - or contact your admin. How should we know? ;)

Comment: is there any limitation to upload large file on live server??

Comment: Further, you should reconsider the *max_execution_time* - it is set in seconds.

Comment: i have set it to  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);

Comment: There could be limitations. E.g. you can adjust the maximum body size of requests in the configuration of apache or nginx web server.

Comment: As noted in the duplicate, those aren't the only settings you need to be looking at. There are a few post_size variables you need to adjust as well

Comment: 300.000 seconds. There should be no need - if uploads work - to set this huge value.

Comment: @aynber how to adjust post_size variables?

Comment: You can use the same `ini_set` with those variables. If it doesn't work, you'll have to talk to your host.

Comment: i have set the post_size variables but still error

"Entity too large"