# Unable to upload large files

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a laravel project that uses AJAX to send files to be uploaded to the server. All works just fine for as long as the file is less than 100MB. But large files like 450MB and up are not being saved on the server despite receiving a response that the file has been saved.
I am using Apache and my php.ini files have both max_upload_size = 1024MB and max_post_size = 1024MB.
Please help, any info that will be of helping in debugging I can provide.
Thanks.

Comment: When you do a phpinfo(), what does it say the "post_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize" are?  Note that you are spelling them wrong in your post.

Comment: what about `max_input_time`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/Apache/AJAX - POST limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit)

Comment: Check also `post_max_size`.

Comment: Any browser errors? Errors inside Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

I know its been long, since I posted this question and I found the answer a long time. But just in case someone is also having the same issue.
It turns out I had a .htaccess file in the public folder that was overiding the server configurations for this specific virtualhost.